# Ubuntu 20.04 laravel sub directory not found on apache

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, ubuntu, config

Made all the settings, home page working but apache subdirectory didn't find.

test.loc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.loc
ServerAlias www.test.loc
ServerAdmin webmaster@test.loc
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.loc/public
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are vhosts enabled? Did you enable your .conf? Did you restart Apache? Did you add `test.loc` to your `/etc/hosts`? Does the folder exist?

Comment: That error message shows `crm.loc`, not `test.loc`

Comment: yes, folder exist, .conf enabled, main page working correctly, no test.loc/path not found on apache

Comment: You also seem to have forgotten a `<Directory ...>` directive

Comment: "_no test.loc/path_" What is `path`? A folder that exists in the `public` folder? So the main domain `test.loc` works?

Comment: test.loc works, on laravel if path not found throws 404 errors on laravel